# capture image from an external webcam and store it in raspberry pi 3

Tags: python, camera, raspberry-pi

I have connected a webcam with raspberry pi and i want to capture an image and store it on the pi for further processing, will the python based picamera library be able to do it or is there some other way to do it specifically on raspberry pi?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
$ fswebcam
```

Here are all the details: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/webcams/